# What is the size of a composite index in MySQL/MariaDB

Tags: mysql, indexing, mariadb, composite-index, covering-index

Suppose I have three columns, A, B, C. They each have a range of *x, y and z* **possible values** respectively.

Does an index on all three columns have a size proportional to x * y * z?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  The size of an `INDEX` is (roughly)

```
  N * L + overhead
```

N = Number of rows in the entire table.
L = Length (in bytes) of the values in all the columns of the index, plus columns in the `PRIMARY KEY`.
overhead = various pointer, lengths, padding, etc

Example:  `CREATE TABLE ... id INT PRIMARY KEY, A INT, INDEX(A) ...`

`INT` is a 4-byte datatype.  It can hold more than 4 billion distinct values.  If there are 100 rows in the table, let's look at the BTree holding the secondary `INDEX(A)`.

```
N = 100
L = 4 + 4  -- that bytes, not billions of bytes
```

N * L = 800, but once the overhead is added, and use the blocking, it will take 16KB.  (Note:  InnoDB allocates data and indexes in "blocks" of 16KB.)

Now add to that table

```
city VARCHAR(100),  -- average length 10 characters
INDEX(city, A)

N = 100  -- still assuming 100 rows
L = (2+10) + 4 + 4 = 16
total = again, only 1-2 blocks.
```

The `(2+10)`:  2 for the "length" of the string; 10, on average, for the actual string.  (In some cases, the "2" is really "1" and if you are using utf8, each *character* could be multiple *bytes*.)

If that table grows to 1 million rows, the index may take 50MB, a lot of it being unavoidable "overhead".

A major exception:

For InnoDB, the size of the `PRIMARY KEY` is virtually zero since it is "clustered" with the data.  Actually, there is about 1% extra for the non-leaf nodes in that BTree and some 'overhead'.